# How to send parameters from ajax to servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I am trying to add 2 numbers using servlets and ajax/javascript. I am getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: and the values are null. Can i know how to pass parameters from ajax to servlet.

**SumWithAjaxServlet.java**

```
public class SumWithAjaxServlet extends HttpServlet  {
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException
        {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            System.out.println("n1 : "+request.getParameter("n1"));
            System.out.println("n2 : "+request.getParameter("n2"));

            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n1"));
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("n2"));
            out.println(num1+num2+"");
        }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calc() 
{ 
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    var value1 = document.getElementById("n1").value; 
    var value2 = document.getElementById("n2").value; 

    xmlHttp.open("POST", "SumWithAjaxServlet", true); 
    xmlHttp.send(value1 + "," + value2); 

    var result = document.getElementById("result"); 
    result.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText; 
}
</script> 
<body>
<form id='calcForm'>
        <table border="3">
            <tr>
                <td>Enter 1st number :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="n1" id="n1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter 2nd number :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="n2" id="n2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Result :</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" id="result"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="button" id="calculate" value="calculate"
                    onclick="calc()" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SumWithAjaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>SumWithAjaxServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SumWithAjaxServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/SumWithAjaxServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
   </welcome-file-list> 

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending your data using a non-standard, custom encoding, but trying to parse it as if it were encoded using the standard form url encoding.

Given, for the sake of example, that your values are `333` and `555`: You are sending the string `333,555`. You need to send the string `n1=333&n2=555`.

Comment: i tried like xmlHttp.send("n1=" + value1 + "&n2=" + value2); still the same

Answer (score 1):

You can try using jquery to do the same with `$.post`. Something like this:

```
var value1 = $("#n1").val(); 
var value2 = $("#n2").val();
$.post( "SumWithAjaxServlet", { n1: value1, n2: value2})
.done(function( data ) {
 result.innerHTML = data;
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

**Update:**

As @Quentin mentioned you need to change:

```
xmlHttp.send(value1 + "," + value2);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.send("n1=value1&n2=value2");
```

In addition you can try converting your values to integer before you passed it in like this:

```
 var value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value); 
 var value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
```

Other than that everything look fine to me.

```
  var asyncRequest;
  function getSum()
  {
     var value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value); 
     var value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
     var url ="SumWithAjaxServlet";
     try
     {
        asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        asyncRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", stateChange, false); 
        asyncRequest.open( "POST", url, true );
        asyncRequest.send("n1=" + value1 + "&n2=" + value2); 
     }
     catch ( exception )
     {
        alert( "Request failed." );
     }
  } 

  function stateChange()
  {
     if ( asyncRequest.readyState == 4 && asyncRequest.status == 200 )
     {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =asyncRequest.responseText;
     } 
  }
```

Comment: I have just started JS, soon i will learn jquery also. But could you please convert it to javascript.

Comment: try converting your string to int with parseInt before you send it to servlet

Comment: i changed to "n1=" + value1 + "&n2=" + value2, but other issue is here document.getElementById("result").innerHTML . I am not reading value.after changing to document.getElementById("result").value it worked. thanks for all your help